# How to read csv file from aspx in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, csv, screen-scraping

Trying to read a .csv file from an .aspx link, I tried this code initially.

```
import requests

url = "https://extra-ibre.fgv.br/IBRE/sitefgvdados/VisualizaConsultaFrame.aspx"

file_name = 'xgdvConsulta.csv'
u = requests.get(url)

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(u.content)
  f.close()
```

Since I couldn't actually get the csv file, I tried this code.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as retrieve

url = 'https://extra-ibre.fgv.br/IBRE/sitefgvdados/VisualizaConsultaFrame.aspx'
file_name = 'xgvxConsulta.xls'
retrieve(url, file_name)
```

The problem is that I'm new to Python and every time the .csv file is downloaded, the result is like in print.
[Printscreen with a csv downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc0xq.png)

I don't know what to do more now to get the table like this:
[The result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U82e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have the .csv ready, your best option is to use the pandas library: https://pandas.pydata.org/. This library not only allows you to read (and create) CSV files, it allows you to visualize and play with the data once it is loaded in your script, by using DataFrames.

Here's how your code could look like:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_cvs('your/file/path/' + 'xgdvConsulta.csv')
print(df)
```

This should print the dataframe created by reading your CSV file, in which you should see all corresponding data

Combining this with your code, you can try:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as retrieve
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://extra-ibre.fgv.br/IBRE/sitefgvdados/VisualizaConsultaFrame.aspx'
file_name = 'xgvxConsulta.csv'
retrieve(url, file_name)

df = pd.read_csv(filename) # you will likely need to add the file path here
print(df)
```

This should work alright!

Comment: Thanks Stan Bergey for your answer! Unfortunatelly, didn't work. The csv downloaded don't is a .csv file. I don't know how to read this type of file (the first printscreen I attached to the first message)

Comment: I think you should try to open any csv with pandas, and once that's done you can work from there. Do not forget to include the whole file path (On Windows, it should look like this:  df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\xgvxConsulta.csv') 

Then, do not forget to call print(df) to see your results!